# Implement sms scheme function in iPhone apps

Tags: iphone, sdk, sms

is there any code on how to implement the sms scheme in iPhone apps. in addition, implementing this sms scheme will allow my apps interact with the sms apps ma like doing subscription of advertisement or services?

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone SDK does any SMS functionality, either for accessing received SMSes, or sending SMSes. If you need this functionality you should [file](http://bugreporter.apple.com/) a bug with Apple.

Answer (score 0):

## Using UIWebView embed a html like below

```
<a href="sms:">Launch Text Application</a>
<a href="sms:1-408-555-1212">New SMS Message</a>
```

Apple URL Scheme TextLinks
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/SMSLinks/SMSLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008054-SW1